# How do I use a material theme colors in my css in Angular2?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2

Let's say I need to use the `mat-primary` color as a background of a `div` using a css/sass class, how do i reference it? I thought something like:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

.a-class{
  background-color: $mat-primary;
}
```

but miserably fails.

Comment: You could try reading [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components).... Which is not to be rude or anything but it's *right there*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first import the theme with

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Then you have to define a mixin like

```
@mixin primary-color($theme) {

  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);

  //Then you can use `mat-color` to get the `primary` color
  .a-class {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
  }
}
```

<sup>***Reference Link: [Documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)***</sup>

Comment: directly using this at it is will result in an error

Comment: thank you for your answer but if i put this in my `.scss` file, all the classes declared inside `@mixin` won't be applied to the document and i'm not able to understand why.